# How to get text Input details from other page

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I need to call text input details from other page, bc I have Text input in one page, and in other page is code for collecting firebase details, so now I want after user put input and tap next to save in other page

**Here I collecting data**

```
  // Check if user is new or old
// If user is new then add new user to firebase firestore katabase
if (diff < Duration(seconds: 15)) {
  UserModel model = UserModel(
    bio: '',
    bio2: "",
    status: '',
     userName: _gUserNameController,    // now here is error, need get function
    dob: DateTime(2002, DateTime.now().month, DateTime.now().day + 3)
        .toString(),
    location: 'Location',
    profilePic: user.photoURL,
    displayName: user.displayName,
    email: user.email,
```

**and this is code for other page imput**

```
TextEditingController _gUserNameController;
```

**Texxh imput**

```
 Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black26),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0)),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _gUserNameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  labelText: "Username",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
            ),
          ),
```

**On Tap**

```
  GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                if (_gUserNameController.text == null ||
                    _gUserNameController.text.length == 0) {
                  return;
                }
                Navigator.pop(context, _gUserNameController.text);
              },
              child: Container(
                width: 350.0,
                height: 50.0,
                child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                  "Next",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0)),
              ))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get your question, and with your code snippets it is hard to tell. So let me answer this in general. On page A you get the input of a text field which is stored in _gUserNameController. And with page B you save the data to FireStore. So on page A you call page B with `B(_gUserNameController.text)`. Then. page B looks like this:

```dart
class B extends StatelessWidget {
  B(this.gUserName);
  String gUserName;
  ...
}
```

**Basicly I want to fetch data from text imput wich is in page B**

and collect them here on this database

[image]

**This is Text imput in other page**

```
      Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black26),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0)),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _gUserNameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                  labelText: "Username",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
            ),
          ),
```

I need this bc after I signup user the will be navigated to other page to add username, and bc of this that after user tap next to this set state to this database collection from image

Answer (score 0):

To handle returned data from page B (using a TextField or whatever else) in your page A, your page A must `await` the page B

In page A

```
final value = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => B(),));
if (null != value) {
  // run your desired code with returned data
}
```

In your page B

```
Navigator.of(context).pop(_gUserNameController.text);
```